# weird pairplot distribution after kmeans clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, k-means, scatter, pairplot

I made K-means clustering to a large dataset with 32000 features,

*Ps : I cant delete outliers because I want to detect them and make a cluster that contains anomalies in my data ...*

--> My Question is :

- ***Is it normal for the ditribution to be like this?***
- ***Is there any other way to analyse kmeans clusters ?***

[image: pairplot graph]

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use pair-plot on the clustered results. Do the pair-plot before, as a EDA exercise. Then, do your clustering afterwards. See the link below for one good example of how this could be done.  

https://statisticallyrelevant.com/k-means-clustering-in-python/